# Laptop battery charging capacity reduced to 52%

Tags: power-management

I have been using Ubuntu 11.04 on **DELL Inspiron 14R (N5010)** laptop for last three months. Before I switch to Ubuntu my laptop battery used to give 2.5 hrs to 3 hrs back-up. But since I have been using Ubuntu, it has been reduced to 1hr to 1.5 hrs at max.

I tried following commands:

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
```

Which gave result as:

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            1 mA
remaining capacity:      4400 mAh
present voltage:         12407 mV
```

Then I tried `acpi -b`, that resulted in:

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 100%
```

When I gave command as `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

```
native-path: /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0

model:                DELL W7H3N08
serial:               7114
power supply:         yes
updated:              Sat Nov 24 11:25:34 2012 (21 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes

battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               fully-charged
energy:              48.4748 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         48.4748 Wh
energy-full-design:  48.9595 Wh
energy-rate:         0.011017 W
voltage:             12.408 V
percentage:          100%
capacity:            52.9253%
technology:          lithium-ion
```

- Someone please let me know, what is going wrong with my laptop?
- How can I get charging with full capacity?

Comment: Can you supply the output from running: cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent then we can see exactly what the battery is informing the operating system via the ACPI _BST, _BIX (or _BIF) controls. From that we should be able to deduce if the battery is fully charged or if a cell has died.

Comment: can you charge full capasity when laptop close ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in which I have installed a new battery that will not charge to it's full capacity. I'm looking for a manner to change some setting in which Ubuntu will allow a full charge, I have a feeling that this has to do with a design in Ubuntu that may be improved upon and is not an issue with Batteries. POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=23644000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=23644000
POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=1995000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=6000000
POWER_SUPPLY_CH

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through the ACPI Problem and regression problem occured during the period from the ubuntu 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10..
Try to install the ubuntu 12.04 or the newer version . Or else check with the installing the Jupiter app. which is mainly developed eee asus .

Comment: Installing jupiter will not get to the root cause, that is a distraction from solving this user's problem.